# How can I connect a N6-30 plug from a L14-30 receptacle?

Tags: extension

I want to connect a water heater to my generator. The generator has a NEMA L14-30 receptacle but the heater has a N6-30 plug. Is there an extension cord available for this?

Comment: Can you provide more details? What kind of generator is this? Is this a small portable generator? As you may already know, your heater is a 250V, 2-pole, 30A circuit, but your generator is a 125/250V, 3-pole, 30A circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Rather straightforward, since all the power pins your water heater requires are present, and ampacity is the same.

If you can't find it, hit the local electrical supply house and get

- the appropriate L14-30 plug
- N6-30 socket for cordage
- 10/3 **cordage** of your desired length, do not use Romex

A big-box store is not an electrical supply house.

Assemble per instructions and done.

Nothing goes on the 14-30 neutral pin.